# Resource.axd Syntax Error

Tags: c#

I am using URL Rewriting with a ASP.NET website that doesn't use MVC.  The site has been working fine and I have had no issues until today when I started to receive 2 errors.  According to FireBug, both errors are on line 3 of WebResource.axd.  That is the first line of code in the files and the line only has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

How do I solve this?  It doesn't much sense to me.

Also, I am using RouteCollection and IRouteHandler.  The site I used to guide me was https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx.  The only real changes I made was I added 2 more links in my page that I have not created routes for but I never clicked on either of those links.

I have since fixed my 2 links and the page was working fine for about an hour and then it started to the throw the error again and this time there seemed to be no rhyme or reason to it.  My biggest issue is that it doesn't make any sense.  A syntax error on the first line seems like an odd error.

Comment: Can you give us more info?  Did you make changes that could have caused the problems?  Did you add any kind of compression modules?  What form of URL Rewriting are you using?

Comment: I added that information above.

Comment: = Hey Ben , could you please send me the resource.xsd sample file. I don't know how to configure the file for using Routing. arlen.n@gmail.com ,thx.

Comment: @arlen 0 the .xsd files are generated on each run of the website dynamically, so that isn't where you need to look.  You need to create a RegisterRoutes.cs file to handle routing.  The .xsd files in this question are just one file that needs to be handled by the router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much digging and research I figured it out!  I just had to add this code to my my RegisterRoutes.cs file:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

I found the answer at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx.  It doesn't really explain it but after doing some digging I realize what my issue was. It was replacing the code in my webresource.axd file, which is generated by IIS7, with my default not found page NotFound.aspx. While the above code would seem to break things it actually fixes it by stopping the linked code from being overwritten

Comment: The same helped me too. As soon as I added this line I was able to fix the issue.